# Why does text overflow spans in twitter boostrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftoplessproductions.com%2Fyuv%2Fproblem%2Ftextoverflow.html

Notice that "Crappy Android portrait 240 x 320" makes the card's text overflow. Is there a canonical solution for this? I could decide on a `min-width` for the `body`, but that would just brush the problem underneath the rug.

[image]

Comment: There are a lot of things that you can do. It depends only by your needs. You can set more width to the content div, you can cut the bigger text, you can make a function that checks how many characters is the title, and if it is more then 10 (for example) to use smaller font-size, adding additional scrolls to the content div and many others.

Comment: I'd expect bootstrap to pick one. Perhaps I was naive.

Comment: Well, most of the solutions refers to few css options set and because of the variation of mobile devices, Operating systems and browsers it is not a good solution to leave the things on them. For example, something like this may be handled by web-kit browsers very well, but not by IE or Android devices.

Comment: You can make one span or div for each `header` and give its width or something to that it stick under that white board

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a CSS media query to shrink to text on smaller browsers

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  h2 {
    font-size: 10px !important;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Something like that will work for phones and h2s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `word-wrap: break-word` to ensure the text will not overflow:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    h2 {
        word-wrap: line-break;
    }
}
```

I've also noted that you are loosing some width because of a wrong layout. You forgot the `row` element and you are overriding `span4` positioning properties with the `.main_link` class. Background colors, extra padings, margins, etc. should not be applied at the same level as `span#`. The native `well` element fits the behaviour you are looking for.

So, to recover the full media width and fix your layout you can use a markup like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="well main_link">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```